# Bad request while deploying cloud function in firebase. HTTP Error: 400

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to deploy cloud function to create push notification (chat messaging) on firebase (Firestore).
But when i'm trying to do this - i'm always getting HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors.
Looks like path of collections is good.

```
exports.notifyNewMessage = functions.firestore
.document('/chat/{toUserId}/chatRoom/{fromUserId}/chatItems')
.onCreate((docSnapshot, context) => {
    
    const message = docSnapshot.data();
    const recipientId = context.params.toUserId; // получатель сообщения
    const senderId = context.params.fromUserId; // отправитель сообщения
    const senderName = message['username'];
    
    if (recipientId === senderId) {
        
    } else {
        
        
        
        return admin.forestore().doc('tokens/' + recipientId).get().then(userDoc => {
            const tokens = userDoc.get('tokens')
            const notificationBody = (message['type'] === "TEXT") ? message['textMessage'] : "New message with Image"
            const payload = {
                notification: {
                    title: senderName + " sent you a message",
                    body: notificationBody,
                    clickAction: "ChatActivity" // возможно, это только для андроида
                },
            data: {
                USER_NAME: senderName,
                USER_ID: message['senderId']
            }
            }
            
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then( response => {
                const stillRegisteredTokens = tokens
                
                response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
                    const error = result.error
                    if (error) {
                        const failedRegistrationToken = tokens[index]
                        console.error('failed token', failedRegistrationToken, error)
                        if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' || error.code == 'messaging/registration-token-not-registred') {
                            const failedIndex = stillRegisteredTokens.indexOf(failedRegistrationToken)
                            if (failedIndex > -1) {
                                stillRegisteredTokens.splice(failedIndex, 1)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                
                
                return admin.firestore().doc("tokens" + recipientId).update({
                    tokens: stillRegisteredTokens
                })
                
                
            })
            
        })
        
    }
    
    
})
```

also i would ask about line "clickAction: "ChatActivity" it only for android? how can i do same to ios?
Thx a lot!

Comment: Please edit the question to show the full error message in the context of your deployment.  If you're deploying with the Firebase CLI, show its output.

Comment: its all CLI answer...
"HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors"

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of the CLI. If the CLI is not giving you an actionable error message, you should contact Firebase support for assistance. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @DougStevenson i have also "Error: Functions did not deploy properly."

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the function from firebase console and redeploy

or

try changing Internet Service Provider and deploy